# How can pass env variable running codeception acceptance tests to run zend with testing database?

Tags: bash, zend-framework2, environment, codeception, acceptance

When i pass variable via htaccess it works fine and zend framework works with testing database. But i want to pass env variable only when run tests. So htaccess is not my way.
Now i try to run tests via bash with APP_ENV variable passed, but nothing happened.
My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export APP_ENV="testing"
codecept="vendor/bin/codecept"
doc="vendor/bin/doctrine-module"

folderUp2="../../"

echo "[$1] Clearing query cache >>> " & $doc orm:clear-cache:query
echo "[$1] Clearing metadata cache >>> " & $doc orm:clear-cache:metadata
echo "[$1] Clearing result cache >>> " & $doc orm:clear-cache:result
echo "[$1] Updating >>> " & $doc orm:schema-tool:update --force
echo "[$1] Importing >>> " & $doc data-fixture:import --append

if [ $1 ]; then
    $codecept run tests/$1;
else
    $codecept run;
fi
```

Comment: I don't think `bash` allows a syntax to do this type of statements, `& $doc orm:clear-cache:query`

Comment: It's doctrine statements.